# What version of PHP started supporting the following syntax?

Tags: php

on my server (Centos5) i have PHP 5.2, i'm unable to update it, i read somewhere that PHP 5.4 won't work on Centos5, didn't inspect enough as i am in the middle of a lot of projects, anyways, here is the syntax :

```
$data['trees'] = (new Tree())->where('parent_id',0)->get();
```

On my WAMP it runs on PHP 5.4.3, on the server it gives me the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for accessing instance members directly after a `new` expression was [introduced in PHP 5.4](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) (finally). Note that the parentheses are required around the `new` expression, as in your given line of code, or it won't work.

I haven't heard of any particular server configurations or platforms where this won't work when running PHP 5.4. If it causes an error on a server where PHP 5.4 is installed, it's likely that's not the version that's interpreting your script (check your server config, .htaccess, and INI directives).

Comment: +1 for the quick reply, i will mark the answer as correct as soon as the time pass, and i would be thankful if you have any idea on PHP 5.4 on centos 5.

Comment: +1. if you could change the distro, I would recommend ArchLinux. If not, you would have to recompile PHP with the desired version. (ArchLinux rocks for servers, it's clean like Slackware/Gentoo, and easy to maintain like the mainstream distros.)